# How do I run a PowerShell script inside of MSBuild?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

Maybe there's something wrong with my installation, I'm not quite sure.
I've spent about two days looking and trying different solutions.  It's obvious that people have done it, but their examples aren't working for me yet.

I am going to eventually want to run an external PowerShell script, but I will be happy to get this working first:

**psTest.build:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Test">

  <Target Name="Test">
    <Exec Command='powershell -Command "Write-Host &quot;Hello, world!&quot;"' />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Running the build script:

```
PS D:\> msbuild .\psTest.build /Target:test
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.30723.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18444]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/16/2014 3:20:31 PM.
Project "D:\psTest.build" on node 1 (test target(s)).
Test:
  powershell -Command "Write-Host "Hello, world!""
  I n t e r n a l   W i n d o w s   P o w e r S h e l l   e r r o r .     L o a d i n g   m a n a g e d   W i n d o w s
     P o w e r S h e l l   f a i l e d   w i t h   e r r o r   8 0 0 7 0 0 0 2 .


D:\psTest.build(5,5): error MSB3073: The command "powershell -Command "Write-Host "Hello, world!"" exited with c
ode -65536.
Done Building Project "D:\psTest.build" (test target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\psTest.build" (test target) (1) ->
(Test target) ->
  D:\psTest.build(5,5): error MSB3073: The command "powershell -Command "Write-Host "Hello, world!"" exited with
 code -65536.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.10
```

I've also tried using using MSBuild Extension Pack, but I still end up getting the same error.
So, it feels like there is a major disconnect, which once that's out of the way, everything else should just fit.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 with all updates so far.  Also, I confirmed that I don't have a powershell.exe.config in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Comment: Your project file works on my machine.  Can you try running a PowerShell console (outside of MSBuild) to see if your PowerShell installation is messed up?

Comment: Keith: Yes, it works in my PowerShell console.  Thank you for taking time for me! :)

Comment: Okay, so I tried this on another machine and it worked just fine.  I'm not sure if the problem is with PowerShell or msbuild at this point.

Comment: I did a bunch of things, but I think uninstalling Windows Management Framework 3.0 made everything work as far as the MSBuild + Powershell thing goes.  Now, I'm going to try to reinstall it to see if that fixes it for PowerShell v3

Comment: As soon as I reinstalled WMF 3.0 it started breaking with the same error again. :(

Comment: You're installing the official release and not some CTP/Beta that you had laying around, right?  What is the value of $PSVersionTable.PSVersion after WMF 3.0 is installed.

Comment: Yes, I've limited myself to only installing release versions.  I had WMF 3.0 and I don't know what the version table said at that point, but I've installed WMF 4.0 and I still have the problem: $PSVersionTable:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2